# Swagger - customising a single class generated by codegen

Tags: java, templates, swagger, codegen

I need to customise a single class that is generated by swagger codegen, I have been reading about the mustache templates and that seems like the right way to go but I only want to change a single generated class.

The examples I looked at seemed to change the template directory location from the command line with -t option but I really only want to change one single class.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If let's say you want to only customize one of the models, a workaround is to whitelist all the other models in .swagger-codegen-ignore file, which means those whitelisted files will not be regenerated/overwritten.

Then you can pass the customized templates via the `-t` option and regenerate the model files again. Only the model not whitelisted in .swagger-codegen-ignore will be regenerated/overwritten.

Comment: Hi @William Cheng, Could you please help me with this question?[Change Swagger index.html logo and header contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704031/change-swagger-index-html-logo-and-header-contents). I am searching for some solution from last one month but couldn't find any :( Running out of time also. If you could help it would be great. Thanks in advance