# How to change Swagger UI index.html logo and header contents in Springfox?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm documenting my API created using Spring Boot 2.4.3 using `springfox-swagger` 3.0.0. So I have the below page now.

[image]

My client wants to change the Swagger UI logo to their own. I'm not able to do so. I have searched and found few solutions and it is not working.

1. Added the below custom code under `/resource/static/swaggercustm.css`. But no changes.

   ```css
   .swagger-ui img {
      content: url('/static/css/mylogo.png');
      width: 140px; 
      height: 40px; 
   }
   ```
2. Imported `swagger-ui.css` to local and triede modifying image path. But this also didn't help.

Can somebody please help me here to just modify the logo? How to override the logo properties?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165448/how-can-i-modify-swagger-ui-html-for-springfox maybe help?

Comment: @omer, Thanks. I saw that before. That seems to be outdated now. there is no `swagger-ui.html`. It is now `index.html`. Also i'm new to springboot and i'm looking for detailed answer with respect to latest version

Comment: This worked for me `.swagger-ui .topbar .topbar-wrapper img { content:url('mylogo.jpg'); }` [source](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4390#issuecomment-378090960)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, There is no Configuration available in `Springfox` library to Customise UI elements CSS and Icons.

If you want your own customised Swagger Page then create a `static HTML page` and disable usage of auto-generated swagger page from Springfox.
Since its HTML, you can change ICONS and the look of it however you want.

**resources/static/new_swagger.html**

```html
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.24.2/swagger-ui.css" >
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./swagger-favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./swagger-favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>
      html
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      *,
      *:before,
      *:after
      {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      body
      {
        margin:0;
        background: #fafafa;
      }

      .top-nav-bar{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 99;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #333;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .nav-bar-icon{
        margin-top: 1px;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .nav-bar-title{
        float: left;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-top: 7px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .nav-bar-select{
        width: 30%;
        float: right;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        outline: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: none;
        background: #fafafa;
        color: #3b4151;
        appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
      }
      select.classic {
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #111 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, #111 50%, transparent 50%);
        background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px), 100% 0;
        background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 3.5em 3.5em;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="top-nav-bar">
      <a class="nav-bar-icon"><img src="swagger-favicon-32x32.png"></a>
      <a class="nav-bar-title"><b>X name</b></a>
      <select class="classic nav-bar-select" id="service-selector" onchange="changeSwaggerUI()">
        <option value="./swagger.json">X service</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 100px" id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.24.2/swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.24.2/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
    <script>
      function changeSwaggerUI(){
        let selected_service_swaggerURL = document.getElementById("service-selector").value;
        loadUI(selected_service_swaggerURL);
      }

      function loadUI(swaggerJsonURL){
        // Begin Swagger UI call region
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
          url: swaggerJsonURL,
          validatorUrl: "",
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          deepLinking: true,
          docExpansion: 'none',
          presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
          ],
          plugins: [
            CustomTopbarPlugin
          ],
          layout: "StandaloneLayout"
        });
        // End Swagger UI call region

        window.ui = ui
      }

      function CustomTopbarPlugin() {
        // this plugin overrides the Topbar component to return nothing
        return {
          components: {
            Topbar: () => null
          }
        }
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        loadUI("./swagger.json");
      }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Can u pls also tell me hoe can i disable usage of auto-generated swagger page from Springfox? Should i remove some dependency?

Comment: Check this article - https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-ui-turn-off-in-production